# How to return a message each time curl fails in a while loop?

Tags: bash

This script starts the netx service.  The expected behavior is that there will be a stuck process, so as long as curl does NOT return 0, we will check for the stuck_pid and kill it (at which point the loop would exit, because the netx app would load).  In other words there's a hanging pid, that is causing the app to hang and this script fixes that.

```
chown_pid() {
    echo `ps aux | grep chown | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -r | tail -1`
}

start() {
    # Start netx
    echo "Starting netx"
    /bin/su - -c "cd $NETX_HOME/bin && $NETX_HOME/bin/startup.sh" $NETX_USER
    url="http://localhost:8080/matlib"
    until curl "$url" --max-time 10; do stuck_pid=$(chown_pid); kill -9 $stuck_pid; "killing chmod process";done

    fi
    return 0
}
```

All I see when I run this script is the following:

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

What I'm wanting is to echo a status each time curl times out and to continue curling until curl returns 0.  What am I doing wrong with my until loop?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming chown_pid returns either a pid or nothing, just wrap kill with a check for an empty string:

```
until curl "$url" --max-time 10; do stuck_pid=$(chown_pid); if [[ ${#stuck_pid} -eq 0 ]] ; then echo "no pid" ; else echo "killing pid $stuck_pid" ; kill -9 $stuck_pid ; fi ; done
```

Comment: What is the # in {#stuck_pid} ? Also, do I put this line where 'do stuck_pid' is?

Comment: For more context I have update OP with the chown_pid function

Comment: Can you update with full answer, I don't know how to integrate your answer with my function.

Comment: ${#stuck_pid} returns the length of the variable - so 0 if $stuck_pid is not set. I updated the answer with the complete line to replace.